# How can I get access to IEC TC 10 database?

Tags: data-request, machine-learning

[Here](https://www.iec.ch/dyn/www/f?p=103:30:0::::FSP_ORG_ID,FSP_LANG_ID:1246,25) is the link with the relevant page. However, I need to sign in into IEC, but there's no option to create an account. How can I get around this? How can I get access to this data?

Comment: Did you end up gaining access?

Comment: @likethevegetable unfortunately, I did not.